# Rspec overrides not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here is my error:

```
  1) Shows Movie show singular movie
         Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text(movie.total_gross)
           expected to find text "40200000.0" in "Catwoman Description Patience Philips has a more than respectable career as a graphic designer Rating PG-13 Released On 2004-07-23 Total Gross $40,200,000.00 Cast Halle Berry, Sharon Stone and Benjamin Bratt Director Jean-Christophe 'Pitof' Comar Duration 101 min All Movies Edit Delete"
```

attributes.rb

```
 def movie_attributes(overrides = {})
    {
            title: "Catwoman",
        rating: "PG-13",
        total_gross: 40200000.00,
        description: "Patience Philips has a more than respectable career as a graphic designer",
        released_on: "2004-07-23",
        cast: "Halle Berry, Sharon Stone and Benjamin Bratt",
        director: "Jean-Christophe 'Pitof' Comar",
        duration: "101 min"

    }.merge(overrides)
    end
```

show_movie.spec.rb

```
it "Shows Flop! if total gross is under $20m " do

        movie = Movie.create(movie_attributes(total_gross: 15000000.00))

        visit movie_url(movie)

        expect(page).to have_text("Flop!")

    end

    it "Shows total gross if total gross is between $20m and $50m" do

        movie = Movie.create(movie_attributes(total_gross: 30000000.00))

        visit movie_url(movie)

        expect(page).to have_text("$30,000,000.00")

    end

    it "Shows Hot! if total gross is over $50m" do

        movie = Movie.create(movie_attributes(total_gross: 60000000.00))

        visit movie_url(movie)

        expect(page).to have_text("Hot!")

    end
```

For some reason the movie_attributes is unuccessfully loading the overiden 30000000 on the second test. I am not sure why, because i have set the overrides on the tests.

Comment: The test error you've listed doesn't seem to correspond to any of the tests you've listed (none of them are expecting the string "40200000.0").

Comment: Yup, thats the problem, the middle test is the one thats failing, it's pulling 40200000 from the attributes and not accepting the override which is as you can see 30000000 :-)

Comment: I'm not understanding.  The error message at the top is from a test expecting to find "40200000.0" in the page (ie `expect(page).to have_text("40200000.0")`.  None of the tests you've listed expect this.  Can you include the output from running the 3 tests you've posted.

Is it possible the the error you're seeing is actually coming from a different test that's looking for the raw float value, as opposed to the nicely formatted value?

Comment: Hmm i see Alex. point taken, i will have a quick look.

Comment: Ah your right, it is another test, if you wrap your comment in a answer i'll mark as correct, cheers for that.

Comment: Added as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message at the top is from a test expecting to find "40200000.0" in the page - ie `expect(page).to have_text("40200000.0")`. None of the tests you've listed expect this.

Is it possible the the error you're seeing is actually coming from a different test that's looking for the raw float value, as opposed to the nicely formatted value?